# Numbering in Align environment not working properly

Tags: align, numbering

I use the Align environment to write an ILP model, numbering goes wrong: instead of having each number following his constraint I have all the constraints and then all the numbers at the end. If i use the same code in another document it works properly. What could be the problem?

```
\begin{align}
\mbox{min.} \quad & \sum_{p \in P} \sum_{(t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}) \in WT} c_{v_{1},v_{2}}x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}}  \notag \\
\mbox{s.t.} \quad 
        & \sum_{(t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}) \in BS(t_{1},v_{1})} x^p_{t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}}  - \sum_{(t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}) \in FS(t_{1},v_{1})} x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}}\; = \; 0\qquad \forall p \in P,(v_{1},t_{1}) \in VT \\
        &  - \sum_{(p,o,t_{2},v_{2}) \in FS(p,o)} x^p_{p,o,t_{2},v_{2}}\; = \; - d_p \qquad  \forall p \in  P\\
        & \sum_{(t_{1},v_{1},p,w) \in BS(p,w)} x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},p,w}  \; = \; + d_p \qquad  \forall p \in  P\\
        & \sum_{p \in P} \sum_{(t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}) \in BS(t_{1},v_{1})} x^p_{t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}}  \; \leq \; Q \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\forall (v_{1},t_{1}) \in VT \\     
        & x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}} \in Z \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \quad \forall p \in P, \forall (t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}) \in WT     
 \end{align}\\
 \\
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Claims such as "if i use the same code in another document it works properly" are *not* actionable, since you haven't provided any information about those mysterious "other documents". For that matter, you haven't provided a lot of information about the current document either. Do feel free to share some information about the document class you employ, which packages you load, how wide the text block is, what the main font size is, etc.

Comment: Off topic: a display environment shouldn't be followed by `\\ `.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you embed an `alignat{2}` environment in a `gather*` environment. Both environments are provided by the `amsmath` package, which is loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package. I'd further use the `\smashoperator` macro (provided by the `mathtools` package) to typeset the material below some of the `\sum` directives more compactly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class   
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed   
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \min \sum_{p \in P\mathstrut} \  
  \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{(t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}) \in \vn{\vn{WT}}} }
  c_{v_{1},v_{2}}x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}} \\
\shortintertext{such that}
\begin{alignat}{2} 
  \smashoperator{\sum_{(t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}) \in \vn{BS}(t_{1},v_{1})}} 
  x^p_{t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}}  
  \quad-\quad 
  \smashoperator{\sum_{(t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}) \in \vn{FS}(t_{1},v_{1})}} 
  x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}}
  &= 0
  &\qquad&\forall p \in P,\ \forall(v_{1},t_{1}) \in \vn{VT} \\
  -\smashoperator{\sum_{(p,o,t_{2},v_{2}) \in \vn{FS}(p,o)}} 
  x^p_{p,o,t_{2},v_{2}} 
  &= -d_p 
  &&\forall p \in P \\
  \smashoperator{\sum_{(t_{1},v_{1},p,w) \in \vn{BS}(p,w)}} 
  x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},p,w} 
  &= + d_p 
  &&\forall p \in  P\\
  \sum_{p \in P\mathstrut} \ 
  \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{(t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}) \in \vn{BS}(t_{1},v_{1})}} 
  x^p_{t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1}}  
  &\leq Q 
  &&\forall (v_{1},t_{1}) \in \vn{VT} \\     
  x^p_{t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}} &\in Z 
  && \forall p \in P,\ 
  \forall (t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2}) \in \vn{WT}     
\end{alignat}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: A large part of what makes these equations tedious to write down -- as well as not at all easy to absorb as a reader -- is the presence of the 4-tuples in sum-subscript positions. If it's ok to create abbreviations for these tuples -- say, `\tau_1` thru `\tau_4` -- and to use double-sum notation, one could rewrite the equations as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand\doublesum{\mathop{\sum\sum}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \min \smashoperator{\doublesum_{p \in P,\;\tau_1\in\vn{WT}}}
  c^{}_{v_{1},v_{2}}x^p_{\tau_1} \\
\intertext{such that}
\begin{alignat}{2} 
  \smashoperator{\sum_{\tau_1\in\vn{FS}(\tau)}} 
  x^p_{\tau_1}
  &= 
  \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\tau_2\in\vn{BS}(\tau)}} 
  x^p_{\tau_2}
  &\quad&
  \forall p \in P,\ \forall\tau\in\vn{VT} \\
  -\smashoperator{\sum_{\tau_3\in\vn{FS}(p,o)}} 
  x^p_{\tau_3} 
  &= -d_p 
  &&\forall p \in P \\
  \smashoperator{\sum_{\tau_4\in\vn{BS}(p,w)}} 
  x^p_{\tau_4} 
  &= +d_p 
  &&\forall p \in P \\
  \smashoperator{\doublesum_{p \in P,\;\tau_2\in\vn{BS}(\tau)}} 
  x^p_{\tau_2}  
  &\leq Q 
  &&\forall \tau\in\vn{VT} \\     
  x^p_{\tau_1} &\in Z 
  && \forall p \in P,\ \forall \tau_1\in\vn{WT}     
\end{alignat}
\end{gather*}
where   $\tau\equiv(t_{1},v_{1})$, 
      $\tau_1\equiv(t_{1},v_{1},t_{2},v_{2})$, 
      $\tau_2\equiv(t_{2},v_{2},t_{1},v_{1})$, 
      $\tau_3\equiv(p,o,t_{2},v_{2})$, and
      $\tau_4\equiv(t_{1},v_{1},p,w)$.
\end{document}
```